# matlab fprintf with formatspec based on value

Tags: matlab, printf

Say I want to print two numbers

```
1.755
1.234e-5
```

For the former, I would write

```
fprintf('%.3f', 1.755)
```

and for the latter

```
fprintf('%.3e', 1.234e-5)
```

Clearly, the first formatspec does not make sense for 1.234e-5 as it would be printed as 0.000

Is there a way to let matlab deduce an "optimal" best formatspec based on the value to be printed or must this be hardcoded by if-statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `%.4g`. The format specification `%g` is defined in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) as

> The more compact of `%e` or `%f`, with no trailing zeros (Use a precision operator to specify the number of significant digits.)

Note that, as indicated, with `%g` the specified precision refers to the number of *significant* digits (whereas with `%f` or `%e` it would be the amount of digits *to the right of the decimal point*).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for that :)